# How sqlmap tests/injections are seen by the victim?

Tags: sql-injection

I wonder if the normal webmaster can get some information about SQL injection into their sites. I guess that it is written in some log, and only if you happen to see the logs you'll see that activity, am I wrong?

Should the attacker be using some TOR proxy in order to be hidden when performing some tests, or it isn't as exposed as to be considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What will be seen by the defender in this situation largely depends on what logging they have in place and where the injection is located in the HTTP request.

If the injection is in a GET request (e.g. `http://vulnsite/vulnpage.php?id=5 ' OR '1'='1`) then this would show up in most web server logs as they usually log the full GET request.  So a defender would likely see a large number of requests to the vulnerable page with unusual data in the parameters.

If the injection is in an HTTP POST (so as the result of a form submission) then most web servers won't log that by default. The web server log would still show a large number of requests to the page in all likelihood, but the detail of exactly what was happening wouldn't be immediately apparent.  Additional logging could be deployed but (AFAIK) this isn't the default in most set-ups.

On the second part of your question.  The IP address that the connection is made from would be logged in both cases, so if this is the genuine address of the attackers system then it may be possible to trace this back to a specific location or person.  As such many attackers do not come directly from their own systems but go out via a VPN or another compromised host.  TOR would be another option but from what I've seen the performance of TOR may not meet the requirements for speedy exploitation of SQL Injection issues.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, this is offtopic, but in few words, how someone could trace back to a specific person just by knowing its IP? I imagine they have to get to the attacker's ISP database.

Comment: Sure, so to track someone back by their IP you'd need either to be law enforcement (you'd provide an IP to the ISP and ask which of their subscribers had that address at a given point in time, which could correlate to a specific person or at least customer account of the ISP) or alternatively you might be able to correlate it yourself with an online identity but that would be tricky and require you to have some idea of who you were looking for...